# Rserve return type in case of multiple statements

Tags: r, rserve

Hi i dont quite understand the return type of Rserve in case of multiple command. eg.

```
a<-rnorm(10);a[4];rnorm(3)
```

it seems Rserve only returns the last evaluated statement,i.e. rnorm(3). Is it possible to get all the three output values with Rserve?

Also i am interested to know how exactly in R can we get the return value of last evaluated expression? Is there a special character in R to get that like in perl?

Answer (score 3):

This is normal R behavior, comparable to the behavior you get in a function. For example:

```
spam = function(x, y) {
  z = x + y
}
```

Here R returns `z`, because this was the last operation performed. To get all objects you can use a list:

```
spam = function(x, y) {
  z = x + y
  list(x,y,z)
}
```

This should work in your case:

```
a<-rnorm(10);list(a,a[4],rnorm(3))
```

In addition, I do not know of a way to extract the last performed expression, **but I would not recommend using it anyway**. This kind of syntax only makes the flow of the program harder to read, and does not save you any time.

Comment: Hmm, I did not know that, maybe something I picked up using python. I deleted it from the answer.

Comment: @SimonUrbanek hi i am too lazy to check the source code :) , do you put the commands send to Rserve inside a dummy function?

Comment: No, they get evaluated one by one (the parser returns an expression vector) and the last value is sent - this is really to avoid traps for novice users, it is more efficient to simply wrap the code in `{` `}` so you have only one expression. So, no, you can't use `return()` if that was the question :)