# How to scrape redirected URL with R

Tags: sql, r, function

I have  afunction

```
testFun <- function(myTeam){
  print(myTeam)
  teamResults <- sqlQuery(channel,paste(
    "
  SELECT  soccer.tblResultsallMore.TEAMNAME,
    sum(case when soccer.tblResultsallMore.RES='W' then 1 else 0 end) as W,
    sum(case when soccer.tblResultsallMore.RES='L' then 1 else 0 end) as L,
    sum(case when soccer.tblResultsallMore.RES='D' then 1 else 0 end) as D
    FROM soccer.tblResultsallMore
    WHERE soccer.tblResultsallMore.TEAMNAME=myTeam
    GROUP BY soccer.tblResultsallMore.TEAMNAME


    "))
  return(teamResults) # no error if this is not returned
}
testFun("Everton")
```

I f I hardcode 'Everton' in the code, I get the required output

```
[1] "Everton"
  TEAMNAME    W    L    D
1  Everton 1734 1463 1057
```

but with the parameter there is an error

```
[1] "Everton"
[1] "42S22 207 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'myTeam'."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect
```

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you provided the name `myTeam` is not replaced, it is seen as character string, and the sql statement looks for the team called `myTeam`.

```
variabel = "spam"
paste("from table select variabel")
```

Does not put `"spam"` in the sql statement inside `paste`. The correct syntax is:

```
paste("from table select ", variabel)
```

In your situation I would use `sprintf`. An example:

```
variabel = "spam"
sprintf("from table select %s", variable)
```

For more detail see the documentation of `sprintf`.

In regard to your remark, if there is no explicit return statement, the last evaluated expression is returned. For a discussion see:

[Explicitly calling return in a function or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738823/explicitly-calling-return-in-a-function-or-not)

Comment: Actually i was having a bit of a brain cramp. I should have put ...  WHERE soccer.tblResultsallMore.TEAMNAME='",myTeam,"'
    GROUP BY soccer.tblResultsallMore.TEAMNAME",sep="")... but thanks for the suggestion which i have not used before. I'll assume your answer is correct

Comment: I extended my answer a bit to include the correct syntax of paste.