# In R using Shiny: how to make a weblink work in the output

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I'm using RStudio's Shiny to make a basic MBTI personality test. A user answers four questions, and gets his personality type (e.g. ENTJ) with a corresponding link to Wikipedia to read more on his type (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENTJ).

To do this, first, I'm using actionButton, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250643/how-to-make-submit-button-only-take-value-from-corresponding-textinput-in-shiny). Second, I'm using a bunch of functions in server.R to make a working weblink:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    # After the Submit button is clicked 
    init <- reactiveValues()
    observe({
            if(input$submit > 0) {
                    init$pasted <- isolate(paste("Your personality type is ", 
                                                 input$b1, input$b2, input$b3, input$b4, sep=""))
                    init$link <- paste("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/", 
                                               input$b1, input$b2, input$b3, input$b4, sep="")
                    init$linktext <- a("Find out more about it here", href=init$link, target="_blank")
            }
    })

    # Output
    output$text1 <- renderText({ 
            init$pasted
    })

    output$text2 <- renderText({ 
            init$linktext
    })
```

})

The problem is that, when I run the app, init$pasted works just fine, while init$linktext doesn't - saying

```
    Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

Any ideas how to fix that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `a(...)` is a list and cannot be rendered using `renderText`. You can use `htmlOutput` in the `ui.R` and `renderUI` on the server side, here's an example:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
        output$html_link <- renderUI({
                a("Find out more about it here", href=paste("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/","a","b","c","d", sep=""), target="_blank") 
        })
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
        htmlOutput("html_link")
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```