# changing first colname in a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I've got a list of dataframes and am trying to change the first colname using the lapply method

```
frames<-lapply(frames,function(x){ colnames(frames[[x]])[1]<-"date"})
```

is returning the error

```
Error in `*tmp*`[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I am not sure why it would produce this error as my understanding is that this should apply

```
colname[1]<-"date"
```

to every data frame in the list

If anyone can tell me the root of this error I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to reference the `frames` list inside of `lapply`. Your function treats `x` as an element in the list, `frames`. Try this:

`frames <- lapply(frames, function(x) { colnames(x)[1] <- "date"; return(x) })`

Comment: @RichardScriven I like to be explicit :)

Comment: Ok sorry, I rolled it back. `return` slows things down so I don't really use it unless necessary

Comment: @RichardScriven Oh, I didn't know that `return` slows down code performance. I may have to refrain from using `return` in my code... do you know why it slows things down? (Sorry - off topic, but I'm interested)

Comment: Here's a good read about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738823/explicitly-calling-return-in-a-function-or-not.  It's really just a matter of personal preference