# Why doesn't this R function work?

Tags: r

I created the following function to append new strings on a vector of strings called "meals". However, when I use this function to append an string input into my "meals" vector, it does not work.

```
 add <- function(str) {
      meals <- append(meals, as.character(str))  
    }
```

Comment: Both of these comments miss the point. The function will work but it needs to be applied in a functional manner, i.e.:  `meals <- add( c("lunch", "dinner") )`

Comment: Because it would return the value of the `append` call. Try it and read `?'<-'`

Comment: I question putting this question on hold. It was not a typo. It was a failure to understand how R functions return values as was exhibited by at least 2 commenters (who have now deleted their comments) and also exhibited by the two answers who also missed this aspect. It could serve as a useful example, but now the closure appears to be sweeping this under the rug. Just because the questioner didn't understand this does not make it a trivial question. It is in fact a rather deep question whose correct answer demonstrates a fundamental difference between R and most other computer languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is variable scoping. The variable `meals` exists in your global environment where you are using it. When you run your function, there is no `meals` variable inside the function environment, so it inherits that variable from the global environment. However, when it modifies the variable, it creates a new version *inside* the function environment. The function can then use that modified version, but it never changes the `meals` variable from the global environment.

So, you can use the function as it is currently written, and just save the result to `meals` like so:

```
meals <- add("Steak")
```

The value is returned invisibly when you save it to a variable at the end of your function, but it does still output (like the full result of `lm` or `hist` that are only accessible if you save them to a new variable). This is one reason why it is a good idea to get in the habit of always ending functions with an explicit `return` or `invisible` statement.

My guess is that you are coming from a different programming language where changing a global variable inside a function changes the variable globally. That behavior by explicitly telling R to override that environmental behavior with `<<-`, which assigns the value outside of the current environment (instead of just within it). For example, this:

```
add <- function(str) {
  meals <<- append(meals, as.character(str))  
}

meals <- "Steak"

add("Chicken")

meals
```

results in `meals` holding both "Steak" and "Chicken" -- the behavior you want. **HOWEVER**, this is generally a bad idea in R. There are times when this behavior is nice, but the fact that it is very different from how R generally operates leaves a lot of opportunity for mistakes to slip in. I use this occasionally to get past scoping issues (often when working in `shiny` and needing to change things for the whole session, rather than just the current user), but I try to avoid it if at all possible.

I would encourage you to, instead, just use the construction:

```
meals <- append(meals, str)
```

directly, rather than trying to wrap this in a custom function that works so differently than standard R approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you are assigning the function to output to a variable in your case try something like these (3 possible solutions):

```
## longest/redundant
add <- function(str) {
   meals <- append(meals, as.character(str))
   return(meals)
}

## alternative
add2 <- function(str) {
   meals <- append(meals, as.character(str))
}

## simplest
add3 <- function(str) {
   append(meals, as.character(str))
}

meals <- c("chx","beef","pork")
str1 <- c(1, 2, 3)

newVar <- add(str1)
print(newVar)
[1] "chx"  "beef" "pork" "1"    "2"    "3"  

newVar2 <- add2(str1)
print(newVar2)
[1] "chx"  "beef" "pork" "1"    "2"    "3"  

newVar3 <- add3(str1)
print(newVar3)
[1] "chx"  "beef" "pork" "1"    "2"    "3"
```

You can also consider an easier solution:

`c(meals, str1)` which will return the same exact thing. `append` is typically only used if you need to use the `after` argument.

Comment: Using return is unnecessary on this case. And this answer prints that value but leaves the user that str has been changed. Check it. It remains unchanged.

Comment: [Interesting discussion on whether to exclusively use return() or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738823/explicitly-calling-return-in-a-function-or-not)

Comment: The addition is good but you still should point out that the return() call was not needed, and in fact the `meals <-` was not needed either.

Answer (score 1):

How does it not work?

One thing to consider:  The output of a function is the last line in the function. for example:

```
x.plus.3 <- function(x){
        s <- x+3
}
x.plus.3(2)
#  nothing is printed
```

This is a valid function but if ran will have no output because all the function does is store x+3 into the object s.

If however, I change it to :

```
 x.plus.3 <- function(x){
         s <- x+3
         s
 }
 x.plus.3(2)
[1] 5  # i get the result printed
```

So you need to add meals as the last line in your function in order to get it to make it outside the function.