# sapply outputs extra row of partial results

Tags: r, sapply

Here's something odd that the apply functions are doing and I'm wondering if anyone can explain this to me.

If I run the following:

```
namer <- function(x, y) {
  print(paste0("x is ", x))
  print(paste0("y is ", y))
}
sapply(c(1,2,3), FUN = namer, y = 100)
```

It outputs:

```
[1] "x is 1"
[1] "y is 100"
[1] "x is 2"
[1] "y is 100"
[1] "x is 3"
[1] "y is 100"
[1] "y is 100" "y is 100" "y is 100"
```

Why that last row, which seems to run through the function as many times as I provided x inputs, but only outputting the y input (and all as one row)?  This makes working with the output a bit tricky since I will need to somehow omit the final row each time.

Thanks.

Comment: your function by default returns the last line of the function code. Add return() if you don't want to return anything. (Try assigning the result of `sapply`, you'll only see 6 lines printed and the "last line" will be in the object receiving the result of `sapply`)

Comment: [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738823/explicitly-calling-return-in-a-function-or-not) may help you understand how it works

Comment: Interesting, thanks, Cath!  I had actually stumbled upon that Q&A before but it's helpful to reread with this issue in mind.  Much appreciate the pointer.  (By the way, I'd make your comment the answer if it were submitted as one)

Comment: Also, I appreciate the pointer towards duplicate questions (I was struggling with search terms so didn't find them myself), @frank.  What's the etiquette on this—should I delete my question or let it stand with the duplicate tag?

Comment: you can leave it here, it will make it easier for others to find answers on the topic