# Jaccard Similarity between strings using a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, similarity

I am trying to compute the jaccard similarity between each pair of names in large vectors of names (see below for small example) and to store their jaccard similarity in a matrix. My function is just returning NULL. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=3))
df = df %>%
    mutate_if(is.logical, as.numeric)

names(df) = c("A.J. Doyle", "A.J. Graham", "A.J. Porter")
draft_names = names(df) 
row.names(df) = c("A.J. Feeley", "A.J. McCarron", "Aaron Brooks")
quarterback_names = row.names(df)

library(stringdist)

jaccard_similarity = function(d){
  for (i in 1:nrow(d)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(d)){
      d[i,j] = stringdist(quarterback_names[i], draft_names[j], method ='jaccard', q=2)
    }
  }
}

df = jaccard_similarity(df)
```

Comment: I would try looking at if quarterback_names and draft_names have the input you gave them. I am not sure, but `names(df) = c("A.J. Doyle", "A.J. Graham", "A.J. Porter")` may have an error.

Comment: There is no error that I can detect. Everything above the for-loop is doing exactly what you would expect.

Comment: You should use the `stringdistmatrix` function: `stringdistmatrix(quarterback_names, draft_names, method = "jaccard", q = 2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return your changed dataframe:

```
jaccard_similarity = function(d){
  for (i in 1:nrow(d)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(d)){
      d[i,j] = stringdist(quarterback_names[i], draft_names[j], method ='jaccard', q=2)
    }
  }
  return(d)
  // ^^^
}
```

---

Afterwards `jaccard_similarity(df)` yields

```
              A.J. Doyle A.J. Graham A.J. Porter
A.J. Feeley    0.6428571   0.7500000   0.7500000
A.J. McCarron  0.7647059   0.7777778   0.7777778
Aaron Brooks   1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not returning anything after the `for` loops. Use `return(d)` at the end of the function.

This problem is also a classic use case for `outer`:

```
outer(quarterback_names,draft_names,FUN=stringdist,method="jaccard",q=2)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.6428571 0.7500000 0.7500000
[2,] 0.7647059 0.7777778 0.7777778
[3,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason :**
There is no explict return.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738823/explicitly-calling-return-in-a-function-or-not#11834490)

you can add print and debug like below and trace

```
jaccard_similarity = function(d){
  for (i in 1:nrow(d)){
    for(j in 1:ncol(d)){
      d[i,j] = stringdist(quarterback_names[i], draft_names[j], method ='jaccard', q=2)
      print(d[i,j])
    }
  }
  return(d)
}
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.6428571
[1] 0.75
[1] 0.75
[1] 0.7647059
[1] 0.7777778
[1] 0.7777778
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
```

You can simply call `jaccard_similarity(df)` too get the values.

```
output  <-jaccard_similarity(df)

              A.J. Doyle A.J. Graham A.J. Porter
A.J. Feeley    0.6428571   0.7500000   0.7500000
A.J. McCarron  0.7647059   0.7777778   0.7777778
Aaron Brooks   1.0000000   1.0000000   1.0000000
```

And assign the output to new variable rather overriding existing `df`.