# How to repeat elements in c() function?

Tags: r, repeat

I am using the combine function `c()` to define the `gradient`:

```
eval_f <- function( x, param, n ) { 
return(list("objective" = x[5] * (param[1] - param[2] / sum(x[1:4])),
             "gradient" =     c( x[5] * param[2] / (x[1] * x[1]), 
                                 x[5] * param[2] / (x[2] * x[2]), 
                                 x[5] * param[2] / (x[3] * x[3]), 
                                 x[5] * param[2] / (x[4] * x[4]),
                                    param[1] - param[2] / sum(x[1:4])  
                           ) ) )
}
```

One can see the gradient includes elements that have same structure: `x[5] * param[2] / (x[...] * x[...])`

**Question.** Is it possible to use a standart function (like `rep(c(...), times=n)`) to create the `gradient`?

Comment: Incidentally, [there’s no need to call `return`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090751/1968) in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do :

```
eval_f <- function( x, param, n ) { 
  return(list(objective = x[5] * (param[1] - param[2] / sum(x[1:4])),
              gradient =  c(x[5] * param[2] / (x[1:4]^2), 
                               param[1] - param[2] / sum(x[1:4])  
          )))
}
```

Or can also use `(x[1:4] * x[1:4])` if that is what you prefer instead of `(x[1:4]^2)`.

Comment: Thank you, a small remark: is it correct to use c( rep(param[3], 2)) instead of c(param[3], param[3])?

Comment: yes, both are the same. However, you don't need `c` when you use `rep`.