# What's the meaning of the (x) in the following passage?

Tags: r

During my free time R studying, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738823/explicitly-calling-return-in-a-function-or-not) article on usage of return(). In there, I came across a function, of which one element's meaning escapes my technical background, please see below:

```
bench_nor2 <- function(x,repeats) { system.time(rep(
# without explicit return 
(function(x)vector(length=x,mode="numeric"))(x),repeats)) }
```

I've played with the codes of the article, but the logic behind this tiny `(x)` (specifically, it's 2nd occurrence) in the 3rd line is unclear to me.

Comment: `x` in this context is a argument passed into the `bench_nor2` function. For instance, if you called that function by writing `bench_nor2(54,3)` then `x =54`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an anonymous function. If we unwrap the code

```
bench_nor2 <- function(x,repeats) { system.time(rep(
  # without explicit return 
   (function(x) 
      vector(length=x,mode="numeric")
   )(x),  
  repeats)) }
```

we can see that within the `rep( ... )` call, the first argument is

```
(function(x)vector(length=x,mode="numeric"))(x)
```

Now, this is a curious way of putting it. But what you get is that `function(x) vector(...)` defines a one-liner function (which calls `vector` to create a numeric vector of length `x`). Wrapped in parenthesis `(function(x) ...)` *returns* the function, and then with `(function(x) ...)(x)` *calls* the anonymous function with argument `x`.

You would get the same result from:

```
my_vector <- function(y) vector(length=y, mode="numeric")
bench_nor2 <- function(x, repeats) {system.time(rep(my_vector(x), repeats))}
```