# Undefined string argument on R function

Tags: r, function

I have an r function in a package that I am developing, of the following format which downloads and returns a dataframe based on the argument arg1. arg1 can only be either of the options "datatype1" or "datatype2". Currently the function returns a NULL when any other value is put in for arg1. What is the best way to inform the user that it is an invalid argument and handle the else block?

```
output_data <- function(arg1 = "datatype1"){
    if(arg1 == "datatype1){
        return(dt1)
    } else if (arg1 == "datatype2"){
        return(dt2)
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends how much you want to punish the user, `warning()` is a gentle way.

Comment: @user2974951 I think “punish” is a very unfortunate term here. The user isn’t punished by error messages — on the contrary: The user is punished by silently getting wrong results!

Comment: inform is a better word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Best” is debatable but in most situations the best course of action is indeed to [fail fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast). Therefore a good option is to throw an error via `stop` or its relative, `stopifnot`:

```r
output_data <- function(arg1 = "datatype1"){
    stopifnot(arg1 %in% paste0("datatype", 1 : 2))
    if (arg1 == "datatype1") {
        dt1
    } else if (arg1 == "datatype2") {
        dt2
    }
}
```

(Note that I’ve removed the [extraneous `return` function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090751/1968) from your code.)

That said, this attempt contains a lot of redundant code that gets more as you have more datasets. Why not use list lookup:

```r
datasets = list(datatype1 = dt1, datatype2 = dt2)

output_data = function (which) {
    stopifnot(which %in% names(datasets))
    datasets[[which]]
}
```