# Why is a function giving me a different answer from the code without the function?

Tags: r

So this is the code chunk I am trying to put in a custom function

```
treated.median <- with(subset(dta, catholic == 1), Hmisc::wtd.quantile(score, probs = .5)) 
counterfactual <- with(subset(dta, catholic == 0), Hmisc::wtd.quantile(score, ipw_tot, probs = .5))
QTET <- treated.median - counterfactual
QTET
```

the output this gives me when running it is

```
50% 
-1.083
```

I tried to make it a function like this

```
ZIB <- function(data, k, s, t) {
  treated.median <- with(data[k == 1,], Hmisc::wtd.quantile(s, probs = .5)) 
  counterfactual <- with(data[k == 0,], Hmisc::wtd.quantile(s, t, probs = .5))
  QTET <- treated.median - counterfactual
  return(QTET)
}

ZIB(dta, 
     dta$catholic, dta$score, dta$ipw_tot)
```

the output I get is this

```
  50% 
-2.397
```

What am I missing here? Why am I getting two different answers? (I have a feeling that it might be a very silly thing that I am missing).

Comment: In a nutshell, because the functions you’re calling (`subset`, `with` …) use [non-standard evaluation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html?q=non-standard%20evaluation). You can’t easily use variables here. If you read the documentation of `subset` it warns you not to use the function when programming. Use regular subsetting via `[` instead.

Comment: So I did this and I still got the same problem                                      
`ZIB <- function(data, k, s, t) {
treated.median <- with(data[k == 1,], Hmisc::wtd.quantile(s, probs = .5)) 
counterfactual <- with(data[k == 0,], Hmisc::wtd.quantile(s, t, probs = .5))
QTET <- treated.median - counterfactual
return(QTET)
}
ZIB(dta, dta$catholic, dta$score, dta$ipw_tot)`

Comment: You’ve correctly replaced the `subset` function but you’re still using the `with` function, which has the same issue.

Comment: Where does the `for` loop come from? It’s not in your original code, and it does something quite different. Anyway, check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that functions such as `subset` and `with` use non-standard evaluation. They are useful for interactive exploration but complicated to use when programming.

You also need to think about how you want to pass column identifiers to your function. At the moment you pass ordinary vectors, not columns. This can be appropriate, but you likely don’t want users of your function to pass just *any* vector, you really want them to use *columns of your data*.

There are multiple ways of doing this — including using non-standard evaluation — but in base R, the easiest way is to pass the column names as strings. Then you can access the column inside your function using `[[` instead of `$`:

```r
table$column
```

is equivalent to:

```r
table[['column']]
```

```r
ZIB <- function(data, k, s, t) {
  treated_median <- Hmisc::wtd.quantile(data[data[[k]] == 1, s], probs = 0.5)) 
  counterfactual <- Hmisc::wtd.quantile(data[data[[k]] == 0, s], t, probs = 0.5))
  treated_median - counterfactual
}
```

(I’ve removed the [unnecessary `return` function call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090751/1968).)

You should also consider using more descriptive parameter names instead of `k`, `s` and `t`.

I would be tempted to rewrite the code slightly to (a) avoid a redundancy, and (b) make its meaning more explicit:

```r
ZIB <- function(data, k, s, t) {
  treated = data[[k]] == 1
  treated_median <- Hmisc::wtd.quantile(data[treated, s], probs = 0.5)) 
  counterfactual <- Hmisc::wtd.quantile(data[! treated, s], t, probs = 0.5))
  treated_median - counterfactual
}
```