# Returning graph and dataframe object

Tags: r, causality

I have the following code which will return a graph of a DAG:

```
library(dagitty)
library(ggplot2)

dag <- dagitty( "dag {
  Y <- X <- Z1 <- V -> Z2 -> Y
  Z1 <- W1 <-> W2 -> Z2
  X <- W1 -> Y
  X <- W2 -> Y
  X [exposure]
  Y [outcome]
  }") 

tidy_dag <- tidy_dagitty(dag, layout = "fr")
return_test <- function(tidy_df) {
  
  tidy_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
    geom_dag_node() +
    geom_dag_text() +
    geom_dag_edges() +
    theme_dag()
}

return_test(tidy_dag)
```

I want to return both the dataframe and the graph though. How can I do this? Essentially I want to return the graph as well as `tidy_dag`. Or maybe just return an object which I can use $ to get a specific element out of it.

Comment: In general, to return more than one thing from a function in R. you need to return a `list`.  For example: `myfun <- function() { ...lots of stuff...; return(list(thing1, thing2)) }`

Comment: @DanY [No need for `return`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090751/1968).

Answer (score 0):

**1) attribute** This will return the plot but with the dag as an attribute.

```
return_test2 <- function(tidy_df) {
  
  p <- tidy_df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
      geom_dag_node() +
      geom_dag_text() +
      geom_dag_edges() +
      theme_dag()
  structure(p, dag = tidy_df$dag)
}

out <- return_test2(tidy_dag)
plot(out)
attr(out, "dag") # dag
```

A variation of this is to return the dag with the plot as an attribute using this as the structure statement.

```
structure(tidy_df$dag, plot = p)
```

**2) list** Alternately return a list with plot and dag components.  That is

```
return_test3 <- function(tidy_df) {
  
  p <- tidy_df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
      geom_dag_node() +
      geom_dag_text() +
      geom_dag_edges() +
      theme_dag()
  list(plot = p, dag = tidy_df$dag)
}

out <- return_test3(tidy_dag)
plot(out$plot)
out$dag
```