# tryCatch passthrough with handled warning

Tags: r

Is there a way to get the `warning` parameter of a `tryCatch` to passthrough the result of the `expr` even if there is a handled warning?

```
r <- tryCatch(
  {
     warning("I'm a warning!")
     return(100) # I want the return value of the tryCatch to be this!
  },
  warning = function(w) {
    # send a notification with the warning message 
  }
)
```

The result of `r` should 100!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tryCatch` doesn’t do this: each handler interrupts the expression’s execution and immediately returns to the caller.

Instead, this is a task for `withCallingHandlers`, which handles a condition and then returns control back to the expression.

Here’s an example:

```
f = function () {
    warnings = list()
    self = environment()

    r = withCallingHandlers({
            warning("I'm a warning!")
            100
        },
        warning = function (w) {
            self$warnings = c(self$warnings, conditionMessage(w))
            invokeRestart('muffleWarning')
        }
    )

    list(r = r, warnings = warnings)
}
```

When we run it, this is the result:

```
f()
# $r
# [1] 100
#
# $warnings
# $warnings[[1]]
# [1] "I'm a warning!"
```

Note that you cannot use `return()` here. [It’s usually redundant anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090751/1968) but in this particular context it would *abort the execution of `f`*, so `r` would never get assigned a value, and the rest of the function wouldn’t be executed.

Incidentally, `invokeRestart('muffleWarning')` isn’t necessary; it suppresses the default handler which would print the warning to the standard error stream; you can remove it, and the call will work the same way, but the warning will additionally be printed. You can install your own restarts via `withRestarts`.

The condition system in R is incredibly powerful but also quite complex, and the documentation is unfortunately essentially nonexistent. The best resource I know is the [*Conditions* chapter](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/conditions.html) in *Advanced R*, as well as an essay adapted from Lisp, [*Beyond Exception Handling: Conditions and Restarts*](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/beyond-exception-handling.html), which is (IMHO) less approachable but explains the concepts more fundamentally.