# How to assign the returned two values in a function

Tags: r

i have a function which return two values.

```
definePosition <- function(nodeList){
#  nodeList = node_names
  # unique name endings
  endings = unique(sub('.*_', '', nodeList))
  # define intervals
  steps = 1/length(endings)
  # x-values for each unique name ending
  # for input as node position
  nodes_x = {}
  xVal = 0
  for (e in endings) {
    nodes_x[e] = xVal
    xVal = xVal + steps

  }
  # x and y values in list form
  x_values <- 0
  y_values <- 0
  i =0
  for (n in nodeList) {
   last = sub('.*_', '', n)
    x_values[i] = nodes_x[last]
    y_values[i] = 0.1 * length(x_values)
    i = i + 1
 }
  
  return(list(x_values, y_values))
  
}

position = definePosition(node_names)
```

Now i want to assign x_values to node_x, and y_values to node_y by below code, but doesn't work. what should be the correct assign?

```
node_x = position[0]
node_y = position[1]
```

Comment: Incidentally, [it is neither necessary not recommended to use `return()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090751/1968) here. I also strongly recommend not mixing `<-` and `=` for assignment. Decide on one ([they’re both identical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51564252/1968)) and stick to it. Don’t mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are returning a list, you need to perform [list extraction](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html). Furthermore, indexing in R is 1-based:

```
node_x = position[[1L]]
node_y = position[[2L]]
```

Comment: Might want to check those indices

Comment: @Dason Oh right, of course!

Comment: @cheriemilk Because that’s how list extraction works. I encourage you to read the linked documentation, which provides more details.

Comment: @cheriemilk I’d also recommend the [section on list subsetting from r4ds](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/vectors.html#subsetting-1) — it really helped me get my head around the difference between `[[` and `[` in an intuitive way.