# Using purrr:map2 to transfer row names from one nested list to another

Tags: nested-loops, purrr

I can't seem to find a solution to the following problem:
I have two nested lists (l1 and l2) and I want to transfer information in l2 as row names for the matrices in l1. To this end, I need to use nested map2 commands, however I either get no row names at all in l1 (using walk2 or modify2 instead of map2) or the whole matrix gets replaced by the test that I wanted to have as row names.

Here's my mwe:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mat <- matrix(1:225, nrow = 15)
colnames(mat) <- LETTERS[1:15]
str(mat)
#>  int [1:15, 1:15] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : chr [1:15] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...

rnames <- paste("This is name", 1:15)

l1 <- list(
  "sub1" = list(
    "a1" = mat,
    "a2" = mat,
    "a3" = mat
  ),
  "sub2" = list(
    "a1" = mat,
    "a2" = mat,
    "a3" = mat
  ))

l2 <- list(
  "sub1" = list(
    "a1" = rnames,
    "a2" = rnames,
    "a3" = rnames
  ),
  "sub2" = list(
    "a1" = rnames,
    "a2" = rnames,
    "a3" = rnames
  ))

l3 <- map2(.x = l1,
           .y = l2,
           .f = function(sol,csl) {
             map2(.x = sol,
                  .y = csl,
                  .f = function(so, cs) {
                    rownames(so) <- cs
                  }
             )
           }
)

l1[[1]][[1]] %>% view()
l2[[1]][[1]] %>% view()
l3[[1]][[1]] %>% view()
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `map2()` isn't working as expected because your inner function does not return `so`, but rather `names(so)`. This is because `names(so)` is the last valued assigned within your function.

To get the behaviour you require, you just need to explicitly evaluate `so` within the last line of your function, so that it returns `so`.

```r
library(purrr)

l3 <- map2(.x = l1,
           .y = l2,
           .f = function(sol,csl) {
             map2(.x = sol,
                  .y = csl,
                  .f = function(so, cs) {
                    rownames(so) <- cs
                    ## Evaluating so will make this work
                    so   
                  }
             )
           }
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

#### Reproducible error:

Here's a tiny reprex that shows why things weren't going as you expected before:

```r
implicit_return <- \(x) names(x) <- "Don't output this"

explicit_return <- \(x){
  names(x) <- "Don't output this"
  x
}

unexpected_output <- implicit_return(1)
desired_output <- explicit_return(1)


## The implicit return of this function is the last assigned value, 
## which is the value we assigned to the rownames, rather than a renamed object
unexpected_output
#> [1] "Don't output this"

## Evaluationg the object gives us the expected behaviour
desired_output
#> Don't output this 
#>                 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You’re right regarding `rownames(so)` being returned; but there’s no need — [and indeed no reason!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090751/1968) — to additionally call `return()` here, or even to create a variable for `out`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You're saying you'd choose just `so` rather than `return(so)`?

Comment: As explained in the linked answer, yes: using `return()` in R for anything other than early exit is misleading.

Comment: thanks CaptainHat and @KonradRudolph, this finally solved my problem! I knew that something was missing in my code and that I didn't get everything back from the map2 commands, however I didn't think I would need to return anything from the inner map2. I'll surely never forget to do that in the future!