# Combination of predefined arguments in function

Tags: r, function

I'd like to write a function to explore a database. "Things" of interest are sometimes represented by several variables. I have understood that I can predefine named values, and use them to assign a list of keys to them, like this:

```
foo <- function(params = c("thing1", "thing2"){
  params <- match.arg(params)
  if (params == "thing1"){
    key <- c(1,2,3,4)
    }
  else if (params == "thing2"){
    key <- c(5,6,7,8)
    }
  <create SQL Query with key>
  }
```

problem: how to "concatenate" several "things"? I'd like to have the possibility to make `key` into a combination of abovementioned vectors, as in `key = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)` by passing `params=c("thing1", "thing2")` in the function. Since there are many things of interests, writing all possible combinations by spelling them out using `if...else if` is too cumbersome and error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `?match.arg` help page, you can give it an argument `sevaral.ok = TRUE` to allow it to take on multiple values. However, the only real reason to use `match.arg` here is to allow for partial string matching in the arguments. (Perhaps checking for invalid inputs as well, but that could also be done separately.) I'd recommend not using it at all in this case.

As far as concatenation, you can make your `if()` statements not mutually exclusive and use `c()` to concat, then you don't need an `if()` for every combination, just one per option.

```
foo <- function(params = c("thing1", "thing2")){
  params <- match.arg(params, several.ok = TRUE)
  key <- numeric(0)
  if ("thing1" %in% params){
    key <- c(key, 1,2,3,4)
    }
  if ("thing2" %in% params ){
    key <- c(key, 5,6,7,8)
    }
  ## <create SQL Query with key>
  key ## for demo purposes
} 

foo("thing1")
# [1] 1 2 3 4
foo("thing2")
# [1] 5 6 7 8
foo(c("thing1", "thing2"))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: I'll go with minimal edits to OP's code. Can't say what their real use case is.

Comment: thanks! That works like a charm! 1) Input checking would actually be very welcomed. 2) is there a way to make the function autocomplete argument options?

Comment: If you want to auto-complete argument options then `match.arg` with `several.ok = TRUE` is a good idea, and that will handle the input checking as well. (It just doesn't demo well on your example inputs because `"thing1"` and `"thing2"` only differ in the last character.)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest creating a named list `lookup` where `names(lookup)` would be your parameters (or "things" as you mention) of your interest and the values in `lookup` would be the "keys." Then you can use `...` in your function to search for the keys you want.

```
foo <- function(...){
  lookup <- list(
    "thing1" = c(1:4),
    "thing2" = c(5:8)
  )
  
  params <- c(...)
  key <- unlist(lookup[params], use.names = F)
  
  return(key)
}
```

output

```
> foo("thing1")
[1] 1 2 3 4
> foo("thing2")
[1] 5 6 7 8
> foo("thing1", "thing2")
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Some nitpicks: (1) It’s generally agreed that it’s bad style to use `T` and `F`, because they are regular variables that can be reassigned (by contrast, `TRUE` and `FALSE` are reserved names). (2) Don’t string-quote syntactic names (the fact that  R allows this at all is a language design mistake): it creates substantial confusion in beginner and intermediate R programmers, since (despite the quote characters) string literals and syntactic names are different things, and are generally not interchangeable. (3) [Calling `return()` is misleading here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090751/1968).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, @nightstand! It's great to learn about lookuptables, which I haven't used in R so far. I'll go with the one from Gregor though. Konrad: R is my "first language", and I'm an intermediate programmer, I would say. Writing bash scripts with variables in quotes/apostrophes is PURE trial and error for me, lol.